# stddev function in plsql is giving me the wrong value

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to calculate the stddev function in plsql, but when I compared the values with java program, it is different.

I need to get the stddev function for this set of values(100,104,105,103,110,115,130,95,91,105,106,101,65,91,95), when I used plsql the value is : 14.032 and using java it is 13.557. could you please help in getting the correct value using oracle plsql

Comment: Presumably, when you say *"PL/SQL"* you actually mean the Oracle built-in function `stddev()` (and not something you have written yourself)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an explicit SQL query which takes your numbers and steps them through [the Standard Deviation calculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation).

```
with t23 as (
   select column_value as val 
   from table (sys.odcinumberlist(100,104,105,103,110,115,130,95,91,105,106,101,65,91,95))
)
, mn as (
select avg(val) as avg_val 
       , count(*) as cnt
from t23
) , inp as (
select t23.val  
       , t23.val  - mn.avg_val  as diff
       , power(t23.val  - mn.avg_val , 2) diff_sq
       , mn.cnt
from t23 cross join mn
) 
select sum(diff_sq) as sum_diff_sq
       , sqrt( sum(diff_sq)    /  (cnt-1) ) as sd
from inp
group by cnt
;
```

The value of SD is `14.0329544118054` which suggests the Oracle `stddev()` function is correct and whatever you're running in Java is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you for response, But I manually checked the calculations using calculator, and the correct result is 13.557121949571583. some the oracle stddev function is giving more value and is incorrect.

Comment: You've got my workings there. So it should be simple for you to spot where the difference comes from.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your comment, can you elaborate

Comment: My answer is a step-by-step implementation of standard deviation in SQL using **your posted values** to arrive at the same result as Oracle's built-in `stddev()`. Each step of the calculation is exposable; you can edit the query to see the outcome at each step. So you can spot the difference between my calculation and yours.

Answer (score 0):

Great code there @APC - I like the look through nature of the code :)

So I came across this same issue today and the answer is Oracle has two built-in functions for Standard Deviation according to the two distinct calculations:

a) stddev - for standard deviation sample; and

b) stddev_pop standard deviation population

```
select stddev(column_value),  stddev_pop(column_value)
from table (sys.odcinumberlist(100,104,105,103,110,115,130,95,91,105,106,101,65,91,95))
```

Example

```
STDDEV(COLUMN_VALUE) STDDEV_POP(COLUMN_VALUE)
-------------------- ------------------------
          14.0329544               13.5571219
```

So use the one that suits your needs...

Some info on standard deviations and which one to use [here](https://www.calculator.net/standard-deviation-calculator.html?numberinputs=9%2C+2%2C+5%2C+4%2C+12%2C+7%2C+8%2C+11%2C+9%2C+3%2C+7%2C+4%2C+12%2C+5%2C+4%2C+10%2C+9%2C+6%2C+9%2C+4&ctype=p&x=69&y=19).